# Use nginx to serve static react files a remote server localhost

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2

all! I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGYNYPKTyno in order to use Nginx to serve my static react files.

In the video, the dev navigates to the IP address of the EC2 instance and the react application is served. I attempted to navigate to the IP address I believe to be for this particular server (ie the name of the server on the bash is like user@123-45-6-789) but I am met with a connection timeout error.

I then attempted to tunnel using putty to the server's port 80 and forwarding to my specific port (ie localhost:6000) but I similarly got a connection timeout error. I know my tunnels work (I can run my api and my react application using yarn build), so the tunnels are not at fault. Also, when I run netstat, I get that the local address 0.0.0.0:80 is currently in use by nginx.

My config file is as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /home/user/application/deployment/build;
  location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Any and all advice would be appreciated!

-- Edit --
My nginx.conf file includes the

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
```

as indicated in the video.

Comment: Check your nginx.conf in /etc/nginx to see what it says.  I might be configured to listen on port 80 already, and where did you save your conf file above, in the conf.d folder, with an include in nginx.conf, as in the video.

Comment: I included it in the conf.d folder as in the video - I did not see a part where the author added an include in nginx.conf. I also swapped the listen to occur on port 3500 (and the netstat once more shows nginx is listening on that port). Did I skip as step? Do you recommend this method or the one you mentioned?

Comment: Maybe look over this:  https://serverfault.com/questions/464292/can-not-access-ec2-server-via-ip-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends, my current changes are I moved my files to a www folder in the var folder of the root and directed that to be the root folder. See config file below

```
server {
  listen 3500;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
      root /var/www/appication/deployment/build;
      index index.html;
  }
}
```

I then used an ssh tunnel to connect to my localhost port 3500 and can now access it on my local computer. The reason I was not able to access the server by the IP address since it exists only in the private cloude. I am now moving on to the reverse proxying and will later connect this to a domain. Cheers!